# Help building circuit

Tags: breadboard

My engineering teacher sent me a diagram for the circuit I have to build but I have no clue what it means. Help is appreciated.

Background Info:
Trying to hook up my alarm clock to a NERF gun that will shoot me if I do not wake up.

[image: Diagram]

Thanks,
Matt (Clue less high schooler that can't wake up in the morning)

Comment: What part are you confused about? It is demonstrating an "AND" circuit, where both "A" and "B" need to be closed in order for the lamp to light up. I don't see anything in there about a NERF gun...

Answer (score 1):

A and B elements are switches, Q is a bulb and between 0V and +6V you have to put a voltage source, in other words, a battery pack that sums 6V.  An easy way to make this 6V is putting 4 AA-batteries in series (plus sign of one battery with minus sign with the next one). The minus sign of the first battery goes to the 0V and the plus of the last goes to +6V.
Get a 4 AA battery holder and a bulb holder and then you can connect everything in the breadboard.